# Google universal analytics dimensions and modifying the tracking code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-analytics, universal-analytics

I am using google universal analytics within react. React is probably irrelevant for this question but just for information I am using react-ga plugin.

Using this document I created 3 dimensions;
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709829#zippy=%2Cin-this-article

The dimensions are company, property, and space.

At the end of that tutorial document it says "you must also modify your tracking code" and provides a link to another document but that document does not explain or even mention 'modifying the tracking code'.

I have the dimensions created and I set them in the code using react ga's method:

```
ReactGA.set({company: "Acme123"})
```

and in the console I get `Set called on unknown field: "company".`

This is the output from react ga/google analytics to I am comfortable react-ga is executing the google UA commands properly

```
analytics_debug.js:26 Running command: ga("create", "UA-XXXXXXXX-1", "auto")
analytics_debug.js:26 Creating new tracker: t0
analytics_debug.js:26 Auto cookieDomain found: "none"
analytics_debug.js:26 Running command: ga("set", {company: "Acme123"})
analytics_debug.js:26 Set called on unknown field: "company".
analytics_debug.js:26 Running command: ga("set", {property: "property name here"})
analytics_debug.js:26 Set called on unknown field: "property".
analytics_debug.js:26 Running command: ga("set", {space: "id # here"})
analytics_debug.js:26 Set called on unknown field: "space".
analytics_debug.js:26 Running command: ga("send", {hitType: "pageview", page: "/profile/34733494-ec46-48ed-b2ae-0ffef6d2499e"})
```

What do I need to do to the tracking code (as doc says to "modify" it or new dimensions won't work)?

FYI - I see the pageviews in the google web UI so I know this is all basically working but I need to save some arbitrary data to be able to filter on it later when querying report data for a custom data report display (outside and separate from the google analytics web interface).

Answer (score 1):

When you set custom dimensions, you don't use their name, you instead use their index. For instance, in your example, if `company` is configured in the first position in your GA account, you would set it like so: `ReactGA.set({dimension1: "Acme123"})`

You can find the official guide here: [Custom Dimensions and Metrics  |  Analytics for Web (analytics.js)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets)